# Substituting a dll, to monitor dll usage

Tags: windows, winapi, hook

Let's say i have a console application that writes to a file. If I understand correctly, C++ uses some dll, to create and write to the file.

Is it possible, to create a dll with the same name, having the same function signatures, and forward these calls to the real api? The application would not see any change, and it would be possible to notify, or restrict certain calls.

My worry is - is there any security signature that the applications check in a dll?
Would there be any conflicts with the libary names?

Comment: This is of course possible, but it's a real pain because you will have to export functions for ALL functions in the DLL used by the process (or other DLLs loaded by the process).  In the case of common DLLs (kernel32, user32, etc) this will be quite tedious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create a new DLL to replace the original, nor should you.  That would have global repercussions on the entre OS.  What you should do instead is have your app use [Detours](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/detours/) to hook the particular DLL functions you are interested in.  That way, you are not modifying any DLLs at all, and the OS can do its normal work, while still allowing your custom code to run and deciding whether to call the original DLL functions or not.

Answer (score 0):

yes, entirely possible  you can already figure out what the function signatures are and re-implement them (heh, Google already did this with Java JRE :) )

The problem you have is loading a different dll with the same name, though its entirely possible you can do this explicitly with a fixed directory. you can load the dll and then hook up all its functions.

At least that's what I think will happen - having 2 dlls of the same name in the same process might be troublesome (but I think, different path, all's ok).

Security generally isn't done when loading dlls, however MS does this with some .NET assemblies, but the cost is that it takes a long time to load them as there's a significant delay caused by the decryption required to secure the dll. this is why a lot of .NET applications (especially those that use dlls installed in the GAC) are perceived as slow to start - there can be a significant amount of security checking occurring.

---

I think, generally, if someone has enough access to your computer to install a dll, he could do a lot worse. A skilled hacker woudl just replace the original dll with a new one that does all of the above - and then you wouldn't be able to see a new, rogue dll lying around your system.

If you are security-conscious and worried about this kind of think, the correct way to resolve it is with an intrusion-detection system like AIDE. This scans your computer and builds a database of all the files present, with a secure hash of each. You then re-scan at regular intervals and compare the results with the original DB: any changes will be obvious and can be flagged for investigation or ignored as legitimate changes. Many Linux servers do this regularly as part of their security hardening. For more info, go to ServerFault.